# c++ assigning value of static int to int

Tags: c++

I have a global `static int xMax`. When I assign the value of `xMax` to a local `int xLoc`, it returns zero, i.e. the assignment fails.

```
int xLoc = xMax;
```

Sets `xLoc` to `0`; If I use `xMax` in other ways I get similar problems, for instance in a for loop `for (int i = 0 i < xMax; i++)`, the loop is skipped.

Why is this so, and how do I fix this such that `xMax` can be used as a global var?

Note: initially I assigned `int xMax;` but that caused a linker error

> LNK2005 "int GameFunc::xMax" (...) already defined in board.obj

It is correct that int `xMax` is declared in `board.h` but only there and nowhere else. Making `xMax` `static` is one of the options suggested to fix the linker error [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28LNK2005%29&rd=true) and that indeed works, but has the above unwanted consequences.

board.h

```
namespace GameFuncs
{
    static int xMax;    // global x and y dimensions of the board
    static int yMax;

    class Square
    {
    public:
      // getters, setters, methods
    private:
      // variables
    };
}
```

board.cpp

```
namespace GameFuncs
{
    void Board::Print()
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < xMax; r++)      // for each row
        {
            // do something
        }

    }
}
```

This is one class in a set of files that together form a `.dll`. The xMax in above loop evaluates to 0 even though in the debugger it has its assigned value (10).

Comment: It isn't clear where you are defining `xMax`. Can you provide an [MCVE].

Comment: “Doesn't work…” Variables with static storage duration are zero-initialized which is what you observe. Note that a `static` variable defined in a header will almost certainly not be what you want. But what do you want, actually?

Comment: I need a global var xMax that is set at run time to size vectors etc. During program initialization xMax is set to a value. I want this value to be available everywhere. When I check in the debugger, xMax does have the assigned value, but I cannot assign it to an int as described. I will edit my question with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've marked it as `static` then you've created a new symbol of the same name that can be seen only in that source file. It's not the same `xMax` as elsewhere so won't have the same value.

Putting something into a .h file is basically the same as copy and pasting it into every source file. So if you'd had an `int xMax` in your header, that would be the same as having one in every file. Then because they're not `static` (i.e. constrained in scope) there's a clash.

Probably you want `extern int` in your header (`extern` declares that the symbol exists, but does not attempt to define it) plus a single non-extern declaration in a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your static variable is assigned some value before you are assigning its value to your local variable, otherwise static int has default value 0.